# Search among all values in PostgreSQL jsonb column using JPA Specification

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I want to search among all the values in the jsonb column in PostrgeSQL using the JPA Specification.

I have the following table:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
| id | json_column                                      |
 ---- ------------ ----------- --------------------------
| 1  | {"property_1":"value_1", "property_2":"value_2"} |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | {"property_1":"value_1", "property_5":"value_5"} | 
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

I can search for matches among the fields if I know the name of the field using the specification as follows:

```
 public List<MyEntityWithJsonField> searchAmongJsonFields() {
        Specification<MyEntityWithJsonField> spec = (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            Expression<String> stringExpression = criteriaBuilder.function(
                    "jsonb_extract_path_text"
                    , String.class
                    , root.<String>get("json_column")
                    , criteriaBuilder.literal("property_1")
            );

            return criteriaBuilder.like(stringExpression, "%value%");
        };

        return myEntityWithJsonFieldRepository.findAll(spec);
 }
```

But the name of the keys may be different or they may be absent, but I need to look for matches in all the "values" of these unknown fields (keys).

Is it possible to implement this using the specification or, alternatively, using the native query ?

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you can use `json_each_text()` function for this.

So this would be "native query" solution:

```
select t.id, json_object_agg(t.k, t.v) as json_column from (
    select your_table.id,  j.*  from your_table
    join lateral json_each_text(json_column) j(k,v) on true
    where
    j.v like '%value%'
) t
group by id
```

Comment: The answer was an even simpler request: 
SELECT md.neededField_1, md.neededField_2, j.v FROM my_database md
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(json_data) as j(k,v) ON true
    WHERE j.v LIKE '%value%';

Unfortunately, it was not possible to solve through the specification. Used native request.

Thank you!

Comment: Yep, `json_object_agg` just build ups original rows. Nice to help!